# Why does making the 'wrong' $u$-substitution still work in this example?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I was evaluating the integral

$$
\int 2x \cos(x^2)\,dx
$$

and realised that it could be written in the form

$$
\int f'(g(x))g'(x)\,dx
$$

and so substitution could be used to help evaluate it. Setting $u$ equal to $x^2$ (the inner function $g(x)$), we have

$$
du=2x\,dx
$$

and so

$$
\int 2x \cos(x^2)\,dx=\int \cos(u)\,du=\sin(u)+C=\sin(x^2)+C
$$

However, it appears that making the wrong substitution $u=2x$ still works, even though $u$ is not equal to the inner function $g(x)$:

$$
u=2x \implies du=2\,dx \\
\int 2x \cos(x^2)\,dx=\int\frac{u}{2}\cos\left(\frac{u^2}{4}\right)
$$

Admittedly, solving this is ugly. In fact, it requires [two more substitutions](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7Bu%7D%7B2%7Dcos%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bu%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B4%7D%5Cright)du), and so it was clearly a bad idea to set $u=2x$. However, the final answer did indeed come out as $\sin (x^2)+C$. My question is about why this works at all. If I understand correctly, substitution is only a valid method when $u=g(x)$, as this justifies the treating of $du$ and $dx$ as manipulable terms. We know that

$$
\int f'(u)\,du=f(u)+C=f(g(x))+C
$$

Therefore,

$$
\int f'(u)\,du = \int f'(g(x))g'(x)\,dx=\int f(g(x))+C
$$

meaning that $g'(x)\,dx$ can be 'replaced' by $du$. If $u\neq g(x)$, then this method seems to fall apart. Despite this, setting $u=2x$ actually did end up working. Was this just a coincidence?

Comment: The substitution rule is always valid, regardless of the substitution made (so long as it is well defined). This is because the theorem that introduces substitutions effectively states "integral A equals integral B" where the connection between them is through an arbitrary substitution. For the purposes of evaluating we try to pick substitutions that change the integral to something easier on the eyes, even though we are actually changing nothing about the problem itself.

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" about the substitution. Any substitution is a valid transformation of the integral, it may just be easier or harder to arrive the final answer using different substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the link you provided, the calculator sets $v=u^2=4x^2$ and then $w=v/4=x^2$, i.e. effectively it has substituted for $x^2$ only albeit in a more circuitous manner.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by substitution is most straightforwardly useful when you can pick $f,g$ such that the integrand is $f'(g(x)) g'(x)$. In this case, because of the chain rule for derivatives, you can just apply the FTC immediately and you're done.

However, it is possible that you can write the integral as, say, $h(g(x)) g'(x)$, but you don't immediately know how to integrate $h$ (and thus don't really know what $f$ should be). In this case you can still apply integration by substitution. This reduces the problem to integrating $h$. But there is no guarantee that this is easier than the original problem.

Thus the goal of integration by substitution basically boils down to choosing $h,g$ such that the integrand is $h(g(x)) g'(x)$ and $h$ is easier to integrate than the original integrand. It is still technically correct, just not useful, if $h$ is just as hard or harder to integrate than the original integrand.

As kind of an artificial example of my point, consider

$$\int \sin(x) e^{\sin(x)} \cos(x) \, dx.$$

Here we recognize the integrand is a function depending only on $\sin(x)$ times the derivative of $\sin(x)$, so we do integration by substitution and get to

$$\int u e^u \, du.$$

You might not *immediately* know what the antiderivative of $h(u)=ue^u$ is. But you still have an equality between the first integral and the second, so you can work from here, instead of having to work directly on the original problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. So, in summary, integration by substitution is not *just* the reverse chain rule—it works in every case, even if this is not useful. I have a question, though. I don't know understand how FTC is relevant in this case. I have often heard that FTC tells us that 'integration is the reverse of differentiation', but this has never really made any sense to me. I thought that this was true by definition. My understanding is that FTC tells us that indefinite integrals can be computed by definite integrals (or vice versa). Is it possible if you shed some light here?

Comment: @JoeLamond First: integration by substitution is ultimately just the reverse chain rule. When I say that you're left to integrate $h$, mathematically I still have a "reverse chain rule" kind of statement. The only catch is that I don't have to have an explicit formula for the $f$ that I need. I can still introduce $f$ as "an indefinite integral of $h$", and then go off and get an explicit formula for such a thing separately.

Comment: @JoeLamond Second: FTC tells you how to compute derivatives of definite integrals with variable limits, and how to evaluate definite integrals by computing antiderivatives. It is the reason why "antiderivative" and "indefinite integral" refer to the same thing. If you imagine a bizarro world with no FTC, the indefinite integral of a function $f$ would just be the family of functions of the form $\int_a^x f(y) dy$ where $a$ is in the domain of $f$, and this wouldn't have anything to do with (anti)derivatives (only Riemann sums and limits).

Comment: I'm still a little confused, sorry. Say we are trying to integrate $\int f'(g(x))g'(x)$, and we find that the result is $f(g(x))+C$. Doesn't this just the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))+C=f'(g(x))g'(x)$? I know that FTC is important in the ways you described, but I just can't see how that applies.

Comment: @JoeLamond The connection is really to $H(x)=\int_a^x f'(g(y)) g'(y) dy$; FTC says that $H(x)=f(g(x))-f(g(a))$. The whole concept of the indefinite integral as anything other than a computational aid muddles the discussion.

Comment: I thought that the first FTC told us that if $H(x)=\int_{x}^{a}f'(g(y))g'(y)dy$, then $H'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. Is that correct, and if so, then how does that link to what you wrote? Thank you very much for your continued help, by the way.

Comment: @JoeLamond FTC says both: the derivative of the definite integral with upper limit $x$ (and fixed lower limit) is the integrand evaluated at $x$, and the definite integral of the derivative of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ is $f(b)-f(a)$. These are really distinct statements, which is something that isn't always apparent from the usual calculus curriculum (perhaps because the first case is almost never backed up by any modeling examples).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to answer my own question. Actually, writing $u=2x$ does allow the integral to be written in the form $\int f'(g(x))g'(x)$, albeit in a *much* uglier way than before. Here is what we must set $f$ and $g$ to for the substitution to be valid:
\begin{align}
\text{Let }
f(x)&=\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right) \\
\implies f'(x)&= \cos\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\frac{x}{2}\\
\text{Let }
g(x)&=2x \\
\implies g'(x)&=2 \\
\int f'(g(x))g'(x)dx&=f(g(x))=\cos(x^2)2x
\end{align}

So, often $u$ does equal $g(x)$ if we so choose, meaning that $g'(x)dx$ can be substituted by $du$. As Ian points out, it is not always clear what the antiderivative of $f'(x)$, but as along as we know that it *can* be integrated, there is no problem.